# prepend a list to a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, prepend

i wanted to ask this:

If i have this matrix:

```
magnetT=NaN(Maxstep,2);
```

and want to prepend to it the "{0 1}"

how can i write it?

Also,if i have this in mathematica in a loop:

```
magnetT[[i]] = {T, Apply[Plus, Flatten[mlat]]/L2}
```

the equivalent in matlab isn't this???

```
magnetT(i,2)=[T ,sum(mlat(:))./L2];
```

because it gives me :Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> metropolis at 128
    magnetT(i,2)=[T,sum(mlat(:))./L2];

Thanks

Comment: For the second question, what are the dimensions of mlat and what are the dimensions of L2?

Comment: Ok,the problem was that i did magnetT(i,2) insted of magnetT(i,:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer <strike>your first question</strike> both questions.

You asked about prepending the [NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html) array to {0,1} which is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html). Any data objects can be readily bundled into a cell array:

```
>> anyData = NaN(3, 2);
>> newCellArray = {anyData; {0, 1}}

newCellArray = 

    [3x2 double]
    {1x2 cell  }
```

If you are instead trying to concatenate the results into a numeric matrix, the following will help:

```
>> Maxstep=3;
>> magnetT=NaN(Maxstep,2);
>> newArray = [magnetT; 0 1]

newArray =

   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN
     0     1
```

For your second question, MATLAB is complaining about trying to store a vector in one element of `magnetT`. When computing:

```
magnetT(i,2)=[T ,sum(mlat(:))./L2];
```

the right-hand side will create a vector while the left-hand side is trying to store that vector where a scalar is expected. I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve and I'm not very familiar with Mathematica syntax but perhaps you need to do this instead:

```
magnetT(ii,:) = [T sum(mlat(:))./L2];
```

or, in other words:

```
magnetT(ii,1) = T;
magnetT(ii,2) = sum(mlat(:)) ./ L2;
```

Comment: Ok,thanks.I was trying "[[0 1];magnetT]" thats why it didn't work.FOr the 2nd problem if you have any idea.I am working on it.

Comment: @George - I added a possible answer to your second question. If this doesn't answer it then try breaking the magnetT(i,2)=[T ,sum(mlat(:))./L2]; code into multiple steps to narrow down the error.

Comment: Ok!The problem was that i did magnetT(i,2) insted of magnetT(i,:)!So, the right is : magnetT(i,:)=[T , sum(mlat(:))./L2]..Thanks!

Comment: No problem! How about closing this question by setting this as the answer?